# pyspark join many tables with the same columns

Tags: pyspark

I have one primary table with columns: (a, b, c, d, e)
and have  100 tables with columns as, say,
(a, b, c, d, e, x1),
(a, b, c, d, e, x2),
....
(a, b, c, d, e, x100)

all the 101 tables have the same number of rows. and totally same (a, b, c, d, e), which means that they are identical but x columns.

The only difference is that the 100 tables have an additional column, x_n, which should be joined on the primary table. Therefore, my goal is to have a final table with the same number of rows and columns: (a, b, c, d, e, x1, x2, ..., x100).

Currently I join them recursively and it causes out of memory error.

```
primary_df_result = primary_df
for tmp in df_100_list:
    primary_df_result = primary_df_result.join(tmp, primary_df.columns, "inner")
```

Any suggestion of optimization ?

Thanks.

Comment: please note that the tables themselves are not of very large number of rows. it is about 300K rows.

Comment: are your rows unique on your join key? otherwise your table will explode in size.

Comment: @ScootCork yes, unique. After joining each time, the df is of the same size.

Comment: You could try to unionByName the 100 tables, then groupby a,b,c,d,e and take max for the other columns (assuming the additional column names are unique).